# Not able to invoke, Java, Javascript or Typescript function locally (MAC OS)

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, node.js, mac-os-x, salesforce-functions

I have updated my sfdx to latest version

```
 nagendrasingh@Nagendras-MacBook-Pro javascriptfndemo % sfdx  version
 sfdx-cli/7.121.8 darwin-x64 node-v14.18.0
```

Ny node version and npm version both are good as per requirement.

```
nagendrasingh@Nagendras-MacBook-Pro ~ % node --version
v14.17.6
nagendrasingh@Nagendras-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm -version
6.14.15
```

I have also installed docker for mac for desktop.

But when I run sf function locally, I see an error.

> nagendrasingh@Nagendras-MacBook-Pro javascriptfndemo % sf run function start -p 8080 -b 9229

> Building javascriptfndemo
> Error: spawn /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@heroku/functions-core/bin/benny-darwin ENOENT
> Code: ENOENT

Has anyone faced this issue?

SFDX version

```
nagendrasingh@Nagendras-MacBook-Pro clirepro % sfdx --version
sfdx-cli/7.121.8 darwin-x64 node-v14.18.0
```

SF Plugin core:

```
nagendrasingh@Nagendras-MacBook-Pro clirepro % sf plugins --core
@oclif/plugin-help 5.1.1 (core)
@oclif/plugin-not-found 2.2.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-plugins 2.0.1 (core)
@salesforce/cli 1.0.5 (core)
config 2.2.6 (core)
deploy-retrieve 1.0.3 (core)
deploy-retrieve-metadata 1.0.2 (core)
env 1.0.1 (core)
functions 1.0.3 (core)
generate 1.0.1 (core)
login 1.0.1 (core)
telemetry 1.2.6 (core)
```

Node Version:

```
nagendrasingh@Nagendras-MacBook-Pro clirepro % node -v
v14.17.6
```

NPM Version:

```
nagendrasingh@Nagendras-MacBook-Pro clirepro % npm version
{
'clirepro-function': '0.0.1',
npm: '6.14.15',
ares: '1.17.2',
brotli: '1.0.9',
cldr: '39.0',
icu: '69.1',
llhttp: '2.1.3',
modules: '83',
napi: '8',
nghttp2: '1.42.0',
node: '14.17.6',
openssl: '1.1.1l',
tz: '2021a',
unicode: '13.0',
uv: '1.41.0',
v8: '8.4.371.23-node.76',
zlib: '1.2.11'
}
```

MAC OS:

```
Big Sur : Version 11.6
```

Docker for Mac

```
Docker Engine
v20.10.8
```

**FYI (Update)**
Works perfectly fine with windows system

Comment: I'm getting another another on windows too. `[INFO] Downloading and extracting Node v14.18.1
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[31;1mERROR: [0mfailed to build: exit status 2
SFDX: Start Function exited unexpectedly`

Comment: Maybe there is some issue starting the function from cli. I just did start it right from the docker & invoked it from code. It worked!

Comment: `Invoked it from code`, what do you mean by this? I thought functions are not yet available in any org. You can only invoke it locally with docker.

Comment: That's correct. Instead using Start Function from cli. Open Docker & you'll see start button, just start it from their. I'm sure we're missing something that's why it doesn't work with cli.

Comment: How where you able to push the function to docker?

Comment: In my case start function push itself & fails later. JFYI I'm on windows.

Comment: @NagendraSingh - Can you confirm if unified CLI got installed/invoking from VS Code (SF commands are mostly used for functions). which errors you're getting from the mac?

Comment: I am able to run on both win/mac(with similar config)

Comment: @YsrShk I am getting this error `Building javascriptfndemo Error: spawn /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@heroku/functions-core/bin/benny-darwin ENOENT Code: ENOENT` in mac. With same config everything is working in Windows though.

Comment: I cross-checked my software versions. I'm using NPM 7.24. Could you try upgrading npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a permission issue, I installed npm with `sudo`, which is not a recommended way. I uninstalled node and reinstalled it using `brew`, https://changelog.com/posts/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x

And now it works fine. I am able to run functions locally in MAC too without an issue.

```
 /usr/local/bin/sf run function start -p 8080 -b 9229
Building javafntest
20: Pulling from heroku/buildpacks
f3ef4ff62e0d: Pulling fs layer
c1e24d4cd1ac: Pulling fs layer
6b6e616a3c79: Pulling fs layer
b25f7b6e2c84: Pulling fs layer
dd458b7374ca: Pulling fs layer
bbe63dd68486: Pulling fs layer
b25f7b6e2c84: Waiting
3e9480657c01: Pulling fs layer
357fefdf9bc9: Pulling fs layer
6fa475a1dd3f: Pulling fs layer
dd458b7374ca: Waiting
c3e1c128760e: Pulling fs layer
4b5b9e1c57a2: Pulling fs layer
bbe63dd68486: Waiting
357fefdf9bc9: Waiting
3e9480657c01: Waiting
c3e1c128760e: Waiting
6fa475a1dd3f: Waiting
c7d316117995: Pulling fs layer
8f7ab136a2c9: Pulling fs layer
1f05f35ceef1: Pulling fs layer
c10fd1b9aa75: Pulling fs layer
6a19c4a9cc6d: Pulling fs layer
5035dafe4b03: Pulling fs layer
491c1ce9c4f9: Pulling fs layer
d2a2659301d3: Pulling fs layer
08d54b036422: Pulling fs layer
4b5b9e1c57a2: Waiting
4bfdb67d04f5: Pulling fs layer
0494ca24cd11: Pulling fs layer
c7d316117995: Waiting
ae945079ae39: Pulling fs layer
03fb7dba7baa: Pulling fs layer
80729d88ae8d: Pulling fs layer
e39f36c309b9: Pulling fs layer
8f7ab136a2c9: Waiting
1f05f35ceef1: Waiting
c10fd1b9aa75: Waiting
6a19c4a9cc6d: Waiting
4bfdb67d04f5: Waiting
5035dafe4b03: Waiting
c706262ff70c: Pulling fs layer
491c1ce9c4f9: Waiting
08d54b036422: Waiting
0494ca24cd11: Waiting
d2a2659301d3: Waiting
ae945079ae39: Waiting
6018af265953: Pulling fs layer
f18d74887f79: Pulling fs layer
17d8a8efaf58: Pulling fs layer
9215aa0839f1: Pulling fs layer
4f4fb700ef54: Pulling fs layer
03fb7dba7baa: Waiting
17d8a8efaf58: Waiting
80729d88ae8d: Waiting
e39f36c309b9: Waiting
c706262ff70c: Waiting
6018af265953: Waiting
4f4fb700ef54: Waiting
9215aa0839f1: Waiting
c1e24d4cd1ac: Download complete
b25f7b6e2c84: Verifying Checksum
b25f7b6e2c84: Download complete
f3ef4ff62e0d: Verifying Checksum
f3ef4ff62e0d: Download complete
bbe63dd68486: Verifying Checksum
bbe63dd68486: Download complete
f3ef4ff62e0d: Pull complete
c1e24d4cd1ac: Pull complete
3e9480657c01: Download complete
357fefdf9bc9: Verifying Checksum
357fefdf9bc9: Download complete
6fa475a1dd3f: Verifying Checksum
6fa475a1dd3f: Download complete
c3e1c128760e: Verifying Checksum
c3e1c128760e: Download complete
4b5b9e1c57a2: Verifying Checksum
4b5b9e1c57a2: Download complete
c7d316117995: Verifying Checksum
c7d316117995: Download complete
8f7ab136a2c9: Verifying Checksum
8f7ab136a2c9: Download complete
1f05f35ceef1: Verifying Checksum
1f05f35ceef1: Download complete
c10fd1b9aa75: Verifying Checksum
c10fd1b9aa75: Download complete
6a19c4a9cc6d: Download complete
5035dafe4b03: Verifying Checksum
5035dafe4b03: Download complete
491c1ce9c4f9: Verifying Checksum
491c1ce9c4f9: Download complete
d2a2659301d3: Download complete
08d54b036422: Verifying Checksum
08d54b036422: Download complete
4bfdb67d04f5: Verifying Checksum
4bfdb67d04f5: Download complete
0494ca24cd11: Verifying Checksum
0494ca24cd11: Download complete
ae945079ae39: Verifying Checksum
ae945079ae39: Download complete
03fb7dba7baa: Verifying Checksum
03fb7dba7baa: Download complete
80729d88ae8d: Verifying Checksum
80729d88ae8d: Download complete
e39f36c309b9: Download complete
c706262ff70c: Verifying Checksum
c706262ff70c: Download complete
6018af265953: Download complete
f18d74887f79: Verifying Checksum
f18d74887f79: Download complete
17d8a8efaf58: Download complete
9215aa0839f1: Verifying Checksum
9215aa0839f1: Download complete
4f4fb700ef54: Verifying Checksum
4f4fb700ef54: Download complete
6b6e616a3c79: Verifying Checksum
6b6e616a3c79: Download complete
6b6e616a3c79: Pull complete
b25f7b6e2c84: Pull complete
dd458b7374ca: Verifying Checksum
dd458b7374ca: Download complete
dd458b7374ca: Pull complete
bbe63dd68486: Pull complete
3e9480657c01: Pull complete
357fefdf9bc9: Pull complete
6fa475a1dd3f: Pull complete
c3e1c128760e: Pull complete
4b5b9e1c57a2: Pull complete
c7d316117995: Pull complete
8f7ab136a2c9: Pull complete
1f05f35ceef1: Pull complete
c10fd1b9aa75: Pull complete
6a19c4a9cc6d: Pull complete
5035dafe4b03: Pull complete
491c1ce9c4f9: Pull complete
d2a2659301d3: Pull complete
08d54b036422: Pull complete
4bfdb67d04f5: Pull complete
0494ca24cd11: Pull complete
ae945079ae39: Pull complete
03fb7dba7baa: Pull complete
80729d88ae8d: Pull complete
e39f36c309b9: Pull complete
c706262ff70c: Pull complete
6018af265953: Pull complete
f18d74887f79: Pull complete
17d8a8efaf58: Pull complete
9215aa0839f1: Pull complete
4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:ba87b3392458b2dc5c9e8791aaff0b95868affba668734335b2c5e2198d9a23c
Status: Downloaded newer image for heroku/buildpacks:20
20: Pulling from heroku/pack
f3ef4ff62e0d: Already exists
c1e24d4cd1ac: Already exists
6b6e616a3c79: Already exists
e705f06d523b: Pulling fs layer
a2c693cbbfc6: Pulling fs layer
a2c693cbbfc6: Verifying Checksum
a2c693cbbfc6: Download complete
e705f06d523b: Verifying Checksum
e705f06d523b: Download complete
e705f06d523b: Pull complete
a2c693cbbfc6: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:47297ad5ff875939fd6f2dfd2a64aea842f3beedbeae070facb85b6747e67104
Status: Downloaded newer image for heroku/pack:20
===> DETECTING
======== Output: heroku/ruby@0.0.1 ========
no
err:  heroku/ruby@0.0.1 (1)
heroku/jvm                  0.1.9
heroku/maven                0.2.5
heroku/jvm-function-invoker 0.5.4
===> ANALYZING
Previous image with name "javafntest" not found
===> RESTORING
===> BUILDING
[Installing Java]
JDK 1.8 installed
JRE 1.8 installed
[Installing Maven]
[INFO] Maven wrapper detected, skipping installation.
[Executing Maven]
[INFO] $ ./mvnw -DskipTests clean install
--2021-10-27 03:22:49--  https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/takari/maven-wrapper/0.5.6/maven-wrapper-0.5.6.jar
Resolving repo.maven.apache.org (repo.maven.apache.org)... 151.101.52.215
Connecting to repo.maven.apache.org (repo.maven.apache.org)|151.101.52.215|:443... 
connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 50710 (50K) [application/java-archive]
Saving to: '/workspace/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar'
    0K .
......... .......... .......... .......... ......... 100%  173K=0.3s
2021-10-27 03:22:51 (173 KB/s) - '/workspace/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar' saved [50710/50710]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[IN
......
Adding cache layer 'heroku/jvm-function-invoker:runtime'
Starting javafntest
Running on port :8080
Debugger running on port :9229
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9229
03:28:49.282 INFO  [RUNTIME] c.s.f.j.r.c.AbstractDetectorCommandImpl - Detecting project type at path /layers/heroku_jvm-function-invoker/bundle...
03:28:49.315 INFO  [RUNTIME] c.s.f.j.r.c.AbstractDetectorCommandImpl - Detected Function Bundle project at path /layers/heroku_jvm-function-invoker/bundle after 26ms!
03:28:49.315 INFO  [RUNTIME] c.s.f.j.r.c.AbstractDetectorCommandImpl - Scanning project for functions...
03:28:50.128 INFO  [RUNTIME] c.s.f.j.r.c.AbstractDetectorCommandImpl - Found 1 function(s) after 813ms.
03:28:50.129 INFO  [RUNTIME] c.s.f.j.r.commands.ServeCommandImpl - Found function: com.example.JavafntestFunction
03:28:50.187 INFO  [RUNTIME] io.undertow - starting server: Undertow - 2.2.11.Final
03:28:50.205 INFO  [RUNTIME] org.xnio - XNIO version 3.8.4.Final
03:28:50.236 INFO  [RUNTIME] org.xnio.nio - XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.4.Final
03:28:50.421 INFO  [RUNTIME] org.jboss.threads - JBoss Threads version 3.1.0.Final
```

Comment: I also recommend using [Volta](https://volta.sh/) as your version manager for Node.js, this way all the global packages you install with npm are handled by Volta without needing to deal with permissions.